# how can i display a value which is retrieved from the back end in all the pages of my application

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 and jsp as views instead of facelets.
I have a registration form, which on success returns a registration number, which i want to display it as a popup. and also i want to display this num in each of my page when and where required.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this your colleague/classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866158 By the way, why still sticking to the ancient JSP instead of using its successor Facelets?

Comment: @BalusC she is my classmate.. both of us are working on same project.. We are insisted to work on JSPs...Can u please help us...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the registration number in session for further use.popup can displayed using JavaScript in your jsp page.

Comment: can you please be clear... how do i keep the registration number in a session

Comment: See [Session Tracking](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html). This will help you to understand the session tracking.