# How to invoke a method with Openfaces/JSF without rendering page?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, openfaces

I am trying to invoke a Save method in a bean with Openfaces 3. While Firefox is not rendering the page, Internet Explorer does.

I'm currently using this code lines:

```
<o:commandLink value="Save" action="#{beanX.save}">
  <h:graphicImage url="/images/save_48.png" />
</o:commandLink>
```

but I was trying `o:ajax` as well:

```
<o:commandLink value="Save" action="#{beanX.save}">
  <h:graphicImage url="/images/save_48.png" />
  <o:ajax event="click" render="@none" />
</o:commandLink>
```

Any ideas?

---

I've found a way to deal with using standard JSF components. Any ideas how to solve this issue with `o:commandLink`?

Comment: Which IE version? Any JS errors in the console? I don't do OpenFaces, but this sounds much like that there's a JS error and therefore the ajax stuff broke and thus JSF page degrades gracefully as ajaxless page. If this is the case, try upgrading OpenFaces.

Comment: IE 6 and 8. No JS errors. However, I've found a way to deal with. Have a look at my own reply to this question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jigar Joshi. You've given me the key hint. It works with this code lines:

```
<h:commandLink value="Save">
  <h:graphicImage url="/images/save_48.png" />
  <f:ajax event="click" render="@none" listener="#{beanX.save}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

I've been to this website before, I was not thinking in assuming that `o:commandLink` might not be able to handle this, might be a bug?

Using `h:commandLink` instead of `o:commandLink` and `f:ajax` with the listener attribute solved my problem.

Comment: Then it's IMO a bug in OpenFaces. Report it to them if you love OpenFaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<f:ajax>` and `render` attribute in jsf2.0

```
<h:form> 
      <h:inputText value="#{managedBean.val1}" > 
         <f:ajax event="keyup" render="result" listener="#{managedBean.someThingToDoListener}"/> 
      </h:inputText> 
      <h:inputText value="#{managedBean.val2}" > 
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="result" listener="#{managedBean.someThingToDoListener}"/> 
      </h:inputText> 

      <h:outputText id="result" value="#{managedBean.result}"/>
</h:form>
```

---

```
@ManagedBean(name = "managedBean") 
public class Bean { 
   private String val1; // getter and setter 
   private String val2; // getter and setter 
   private String res; // getter and setter 
   ... 

   public void someThingToDoListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) { 
       //res = some processing
    }

}
```

---

**Also See**

- [how-to-update-a-value-displayed-in-the-page-without-refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852890/how-to-update-a-value-displayed-in-the-page-without-refreshing)
- [JSF2: Ajax in JSF – using f:ajax tag](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/)

Comment: Thank you Jigar Joshi. You've given me the key hint to solve my problem!