# Java Servlet and Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

Im currently making a `Java Servlet` that can *respond to jquery calls* and send back data for my web page to use. But this is only a response using the `doGet` method.

Is there a way to have multiple methods in a `Servlet` and call them each with `JQuery`?

i.e. have a method called Hello and it returns a String "Hello" and another method called Bye and it returns a String "Bye". Is there a way using *Jquery* or some other technology to do this kind of thing?

Im quite new to servlets so Im still not sure what they are fully capable of. So is the `doGet` the only method to 'get in' and I just branch responses from there?

Comment: Take a look at [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/primer.html), and the [MVC pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/web-tier/web-tier5.html).

Answer (score 3):

With Servlet you can either call the service method, so may be for your scenario you could pass the parameter to decide which method to invoke from `doGet()`

also you could identify if request is coming from AJAX using header check

There are other technologies available which will allow you directly invoke method See JSF, DWR

**See**

- [How to invoke a method with Openfaces/JSF without rendering page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128065/how-to-invoke-a-method-with-openfaces-jsf-without-rendering-page)
- [How to call a java method from jsp by clicking a menu in html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983961/how-to-call-a-java-method-from-jsp-by-clicking-a-menu-in-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use reflection in my controllers(servlets) which basically let me achieve this.

If I have a servlet called UserController

The main url to call the servlet will be /user. 
Knowing this, I always pass my first parameter as ?action=add

Then in my servlet I have a method called add or actionAdd. Whichever you prefer.

Then I use the following code;

```
String str = String str = request.getParameter("action").toLowerCase();
Method method = getClass().getMethod(str, HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class);
method.invoke(this, request, response);
```

Explanation:

str will have the action parameters value, add in this case.
Method method will be a reference to a method with the given name(str) and its expected parameter types.

I then invoke the method, passing the context, request and response.

The add method would look something like this;

```
public void add(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    //do add stuff

        String url = "/user/index.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        request.setAttribute("User", user);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
}
```

I don't know about only passing back a string. But this should get you a basic idea.

**Do note that reflection can cost you, altohugh it shouldnt really affect you much like this. And it is error prone as method names/signatures need to match perfectly.**

So from jquery you would do an ajax request to the url:

```
 localhost/projectname/user/add (if you use urlrewrite)
 or
 localhost/projectname/user?action=add (if you dont)
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlet Container supports Custom `Http` methods since Servlet 3.0. For Ex,

```
public void doHello(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
   //implement your custom method
}
```

The above method in Servlet can be invoked using `hello` http method.

But i am not sure if `jquery` has the support to invoke custom HTTP methods.

If it does not have, then the only option you have.

- Invoke Servlet using GET and action parameter.
- Read the action parameter and invoke the method using reflection.