# <h:inputText> howto execute bean method on blur?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I have `<h:inputText>` on form and what I need is to execute some method from backing bean on BLUR event:

```
public void test()  
{  
  System.out.print("HELLO!");  
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `<f:ajax>`

```
<h:form>           
      <h:inputText value="#{managedBean.val}" > 
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="result" listener="#{managedBean.test}"/> 
      </h:inputText>           
</h:form>
```

---

```
@ManagedBean(name = "managedBean") 
public class Bean { 
   private String val; // getter and setter 

   ... 

   public void test() {  
      System.out.print("HELLO!");  
   }  

}
```

---

**Alternative** :

If you are using richfaces then you can use [`a4j:jsFunction`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jsFunction.jsf?c=jsFunction&tab=usage)

---

**See Also**

- [JSF2: Ajax in JSF – using f:ajax tag](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/)
- [How-to-update-a-value-displayed-in-the-page-without-refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852890/how-to-update-a-value-displayed-in-the-page-without-refreshing)

Comment: Thank you, Jigar. But are you sure that listener is working? It writes HELLO to console only after refresh of page...

Comment: Yes it will work. may be you can change the event to onkeyup to debug