# Richfaces popup panel

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

How can I invoke a method from backing bean before popup panel shows?

```
<h:commandButton value="Call the popup" action="#{bean.doSomething}" >
    <rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show" />
</h:commandButton>

<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" resizeable="true" onmaskclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()">
   ...
</rich:popupPanel>
```

In this case *doSomething()* method doesn't invoke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nest `a4j:ajax` in the `commandButton` or use `a4j:commandButton`. These two components have an `oncomplete` attribute where you could put a code that opens the popup dialog like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Call the popup" action="#{bean.doSomething}" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.show()">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

This will perform an ajax request when the button is clicked and will open the popup when the request is finished.

Comment: I might add that if you want to rerender the contents of the popup as a result of the action (lazy-loading data for instance), you'll want to stick a render attribute on the a4j:commandButton tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `f:ajax` on successful response show the popup

**Also See**

- [how-to-update-a-value-displayed-in-the-page-without-refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852890/how-to-update-a-value-displayed-in-the-page-without-refreshing)

Comment: Be a little more detailed about where to use f:ajax, if I use f:ajax before rich:componentControl the popup panel doesn't show. Do you mean to put f:ajax in rich:popupPanel?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use an actionListener in this case. The action is used to change the view and I assume you just want to show the popup.

MAG,
Milo

Comment: Negative. The purpose of the actionListener is to invoke a server-side code. What he wants/needs is to invoke client-side code (that shows the popup).