# Call Java method inside java script - Oracle ADF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, partial

When user submits one page, I need to update hidden field values before submitting. How can I achieve that?

```
<af:button text="Continue" action="#{addAccount_backing.addBankAccountConfirm}" partialSubmit="true" onclick="goSubmit(this);"/>
```

Inside goSubmit java script function I need to update hidden field values before posting. I'm using ADF framework and JSF for view.

Comment: Are you want a `Java method' in client side script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `f:ajax` and do the stuff you need, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852890/how-to-update-a-value-displayed-in-the-page-without-refreshing) example